# Are `-name` and `-exec` options or non-option arguments of `find`?

Tags: find, arguments, options

Are `-name` and `-exec` options or  non-option arguments of `find`? They look like short options, and they are called find expressions, if I am not mistaken. For example,

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec echo {} \;
```

Comment: They're not options they're operands.

Comment: Do you mean "optional"? What difference comes up in your interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

`-name`, `-exec`, `-print` etc. are not *option* to the `find` utility but *operands*. An operand is

> An argument to a command that is generally used as an object supplying information to a utility necessary to complete its processing. Operands generally follow the options in a command line.

(from [the POSIX definitions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html)), i.e. a non-option that tells the utility what to do (as the `file` in the command `rm file` which tells `rm` what file to delete).

[The POSIX standard description of the `find` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/find.html) calls these operands *primaries* and this is also what they are called on BSD systems.

In the GNU `find` manual, they are called *expressions* and are divided into groups depending on their use:

- Tests (e.g. `-name`, `-mtime`)
- Actions (e.g. `-delete`, `-print`)
- Global options (e.g. `-maxdepth`, `-depth`)
- Positional options (e.g. `-follow`)
- Operators (e.g. `-not`, `-and`)

---

The POSIX standard `find` only has two real options, `-H` and `-L`.  These has to do with how symbolic links are to be handled.

The POSIX standard does not define any multi-character option or "long option" for any utility.  This does no preclude implementations from adding long options though, and GNU utilities in particular are well known for adding expressive long options for extended convenience features.

Comment: Do "option" find expressions  work like real options? Is that why they are called options?

Comment: What is the difference between global options  and positional options?

Comment: tests and actions are find expressions evaluable to true or false. Are option find expressions evaluable, and if yes, also to true or false?

Answer (score 1):

The `find` command has only two options [in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) (`-H`, `-L`), or five [in GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Invoking-find.html#Invoking-find) (also `-P`, `-D`*`debug_opt`*, `-O#`). All other arguments are not options, and thus are non-option arguments.

Notably, options to `find` *precede* the paths, while all find expressions should follow them: `find [option...] path... [expression...]`. (GNU find has some additional primaries that it also calls "options" sometimes, like `-maxdepth`; they're not true options, appearing inside the expression part, but I suppose the warning messages are more comprehensible if they call them that way).