# What are really the prefix rules for options: - and -- ? Why is the find command not compatible with the --name option?

Tags: linux, find, options

Once, I've learned that options of *Linux* commands came in two manners:

- those of one letter, prefixed by a `-`
- those of many letters, prefixed by a `--`

And this works in 95% of the cases.

But not, for example, for the `find` command. This one fails:

```bsh
find . --name myfilename
```

And this one is working:

```bsh
find . -name myfilename
```

Either I'm wrong with my belief that options start by `-` or `--` depending on their number of letters,

Either `find` command should, I agree, retain for compatibility it's ability to run with the `-name` option, but it should also accept the `--name` option.

What's the truth ?

Answer (score 2):

What you're learned is [more like what you'd call *guidelines* than actual rules](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJVBvvS57j0). Or maybe they should be called customs.

The harsh reality is that there are no rules and trying to model the existing tools, with all of the historical compatibility baggage they have, through some clean and nice rules is bound to end in tears.

The tests/actions/whatever of `find` are one thing, single dash long arguments like in X utilities (`-geometry`) are another, stuff like `tar czf` and `dd if=...` yet another.

See also:

- [The discrimination between short and long option is only `-`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/257672/170373) for some background on the various long options
- [Are `-name` and `-exec` options or non-option arguments of `find`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/483081/170373) esp. if you want to hair-split on what `-name`  actually is for `find`